# Batch scripting 'start' does not seem to have access to system PATH

Tags: batch-file, docker-compose, path

I am writing batch scripts to start up some services. One of them is driven by docker-compose, and so I would like to call `docker-compose up`. I would like to have a persistent window with its log output to monitor and debug the system.

If I do this manually, I simply have to navigate to the folder containing my `docker-compose.yml` file and type `docker-compose up` to get this result (which is what I desire):
[image]

So far I've tried this:

```
cd /D ../STINGER-OP-Deploy/ENGINE-SOCKET
set PATH= %cd%
::echo %PATH%

:: Start up docker-compose
cd %PATH% & start "LPG-Docker" dockerStart.bat
```

Where `dockerStart.bat` is a batch file containing only:

```
docker-compose up
```

and am met with

```
'docker-compose' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Which makes me think that the window created by `start` does not have correct access to my system path. Am I right in thinking this? How/can this be overcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`path` is a system-established variable which contains a list of directories which tells the OS where to look for executables that are not contained in the current directory. Use another variable name. –